# Как узнать с date(Ymd) "вчера" и "позавчера"

Tags: php

Как узнать с этого формата 20130727 date(Ymd), когда это было ? Вчера или позавчера ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-нибудь так:

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('20130727'));
echo 'Дата: '.$cur_date.'<br>';
$date = new DateTime($cur_date);
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo 'Днем раньше: '.$date->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
$date = new DateTime($cur_date);
$date->modify('-2 day');
echo 'Позавчера: '.$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Работу скрипта - [смотрим тут](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kvh-b6n)